# Is there any implicit providing `some.long.expression.let(x => ...)` syntax

Tags: scala, scalaz, idioms

For example I want to get `x * (x - 1)` in the end of my long expression without separating it into two lines and introducing unnecessary variables. I could achieve it with simple implicit:

```
scala> implicit class Rich[T](x: T) { def let[U](f: T => U) = f(x)}
defined class Rich

scala> List(1,2,3).map(_ + 1).sum.let(x => x * (x - 1))
res199: Int = 72
```

But is there any such built-in implicit in Scala, Scalaz, Twitter Utils or some another library?

Comment: List(1,2,3).map(_ + 1).sum match{case x=>x*(x-1)} . Looks a bit ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalaz has it as [part of its `IdOps` implicits](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/IdOps.scala).  It's called `|>`.

```
long.complex(expression) |> { x => x*(x+1) }
```

That said, pulling in all of Scalaz for a one-liner is a bit inefficient.

Also, don't forget that `match` already works this way, just with awkward precedence.

```
((long.complex(expression)) match { case x => x*(x+1) })
```

Because of that awkwardness, it's not much better (though it is more efficient than *every* other alternative, at least until the optimizer is improved a bit more) than

```
Some(long.complex(expression)).map(x => x*(x+1)).get
```

And you could also

```
long.complex(expression) :: Nil map (x => x*(x+1)) head
```

if you were willing to turn on unary postfix operators.

Comment: Thanks! Identity is exactly what i'm looking for! I would also add `import scalaz.syntax.id._` for people who don't know selfless convention

Answer (score 1):

The closest way I've found is:

```
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._
scala> List(1,2,3).map(_ + 1).sum.some.map(x => x * (x - 1)).get
res201: Int = 72
```